# Can I Use Google Fit API without develop a WearOS companion APP and Google Fit APP?

Tags: google-fit

I am planning to Retrieve Google Fit API without installing any additional Google Fit APP or Companion APP, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need to install the Google Fit app to use the APIs or the Fit platform.